# Can I use "Spring Webflow" without "Spring Security"?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflow, form-authentication

I need to add a workflow engine on my web application.

I use `Form-Based Authentication` for my login.

I tried to use `Spring Webflow`, but as I was searching, I realised that every link I have found, refers also to `Spring Security`.

Therefor, I would like to know, if I can use `Spring Webflow` without `Spring Security`.

Does `Spring Webflow` work without `Spring Security` or not?

In case you know the answer, please leave a comment below.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: yes. they are completely independent projects

Comment: @rptmat57 : Thank you very much for your answer. I have a much better feeling when i work on something and have somebody who can confirm that the logic I try to follow will actually lead to a result and not to a deadend.